# Install Solaris 8 on Qemu-SPARC

Tags: solaris, qemu, scientific-linux

I've been struggling with installing Solaris 8 Sparc-32bit on Qemu for a while. 
So far I've viewed several sites with instructions on how to install Solaris-sparc32bit on Qemu. But only yesterday was I successful. 
Anyway, I downloaded and compiled the latest (3 weeks ago) of Qemu and obtained the ISO of Solaris 8 from my friend.

Using the command: 
`sparc-softmmu/qemu-system-sparc -M SS-5 -bios ss5.bin -hda HDD/sunos8.img -m 256 -nographic`

I was able to successfully install Solaris8.

I used this command to start the installation:

```
sparc-softmmu/qemu-system-sparc -M SS-5 -hda HDD/sunos8.img
```

The problem is the OS does not boot up as it should. When I run the above command here's the output that i receive:

```
VNC server running on '::1:5900'
```

Then I use TigerVNC to view using the command:

```
vncviewer localhost:5900
```

After that I get the QEMU gui. Here's a sample of the initial output:

```
Welcome to OpenBIOS v1.1 built on Mar 10 2014
 Type 'help' for detailed information
Trying disk...
SunOS Release 5.8 Version Generic_108528-22 32-bit
Copyright 1983-2003 Sun Microsystems, Inc.
Hostname: localhost
The /file system (dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s0) is being checked.
dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s0: INCORRECT BLOCK COUNT I=17266 (2 SHOULD BE 0) (CORRECTED)
dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s0: 39877 DUP I=17356
dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s0: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.

WARNING - Unable to repair the / filesystem. Run fsck
manually (fsck -F ufs dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s0). Eit the shell when
done to continue the boot process
```

Here's an image:
[image]

The command prompt ask the user to press Return and the system will reboot. 
However, after pressing return the system just prints out a single line error message forever (basically like a loop that runs forever). So I don't have a chance to see the error line and post it here.

PLEASE Help!

Machine/Method:
Windows 7 64-bit, Xeon (8-core), 6 Gig ram, Nvidia Quadro FX 1800
Running Scientific Linux 64-bit in VmWare (VmWare tools installed)
I updated Scientific Linux before compiling Qemu

Answer (score 3):

When you started your installed HD image, you didn't add -bios ss5.bin to the command line like you did during the installation and also you didn't add -nographic.

This means QEMU would have used OpenBIOS instead of the Sun OBP ROM used for the installation which have different device trees that may confuse the OS. I would highly recommend sticking with one particular ROM for both installation and use.

If you want a graphical console with the Sun OBP ROM image then you need to boot like this:

```
sparc-softmmu/qemu-system-sparc -M SS-5 \
    -bios ss5.bin -hda HDD/sunos8.img \
    -m 256 -g 1024x768 -vga cg3
```

That should get you a plain framebuffer which is enough to boot into the Solaris 8 XWindows installer.

I believe the issue with Java not starting is until under investigation.

Comment: Mark and goldilocks thanks for the suggestion. I know in the line that I typed I didn't specify the bios. However, whether or not OpenBIOS or Sun OBP ROM is used the installation does not boot. I've been dealing with this issue for a long time. I've tried several commands using the 'ss5.bin' file. Still doesn't bootup. In fact, when I use the command you suggested I get the same error all the time. Basically, after entering the command in a terminal I get to the Qemu prompt and type: 'boot disk0' (I'm assuming that disk0 is the HDD). 20 seconds after executing that command the system restarts.

Comment: Alright going back to basics, the first thing to notice is that your disk image is claiming to be corrupt on first boot which is why you are seeing a lot of the problems. Solaris is quite fussy about disk partioning, and there are various guides as to how to do this - which one did you use?

Comment: You asked: "Which one did you use?". I used the `sparc-softmmu/qemu-system-sparc -M SS-5 -bios ss5.bin -hda HDD/sunos8.img -m 256 -nographic`. I decided to restart this whole procedure by installing Solaris9 instead. I used this command `sparc-softmmu/qemu-system-sparc -bios ss5.bin -hda HDD/sunos8a.img -cdrom SolarisTest/sol9v1.iso -m 256 -nographic` I eliminated the `-M SS-5` option because, and I don't know why, the Qemu would restart itself. This happened many times without any error message. I'm currently in the middle of Solaris9 installation. I'll update you once it's finished.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining better, but for "which one did you use?" I meant the disk partitioning setup. As recently as last week, I used the guide at http://virtuallyfun.superglobalmegacorp.com/?p=281 to prepare and label a 36G disk and installed Solaris 8 into it. After a reboot the disk was picked up correctly with no errors, and I was even able to run X (note: I am currently running a QEMU 2.2-rc2 on Linux)

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the reply. ---IN Qemu---> AVAILABLE DRIVE TYPES:
        0. Auto configure
        1. Quantum ProDrive 80S
        2. Quantum ProDrive 105S
        3. CDC Wren IV 94171-344
        4. SUN0104
        5. SUN0207
        6. SUN0327
        7. SUN0340
        8. SUN0424
        9. SUN0535
        10. SUN0669
        11. SUN1.0G
        12. SUN1.05
        13. SUN1.3G
        14. SUN2.1G
        15. SUN2.9G
        16. Zip 100
        17. Zip 250
        18. other
Specify disk type (enter its number): 15
selecting c0t0d0
(I created a 3G disk, so I picked #15) @Mark

Comment: Did that work with a 3G disk? If not, please try using the instructions in the URL above since that is a "known good" configuration with the C/H/S precalculated and I can confirm it works here. Note that qcow2 files are sparse and so even with a 36G size specified won't actually take up that amount of physical disk space.